# jsp tags doesn't work in webflow Pizza example

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-webflow

I do simple webflow example

But when I add

```
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

I get exception, when I open the jsp:

```
root cause 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/flows/practice/practiceType.jsp (line: 2, column: 5) &lt;jsp:output&gt; must not be used in standard syntax
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseStandardAction(Parser.java:1152)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1451)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:50)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:187)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

What is wrong?

practiceType.jsp

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page">
 <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

 <head><title>Spizza</title></head>
 <body>
 <h2>Thankyouforyourorder!</h2>

 </body>
</html>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<!-- <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean> -->

<!-- Tiles config -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" />
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/views.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<context:component-scan base-package="free.lesya.test" />

<beans:import resource="EntityOperatorBean.xml" />

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize">
        <beans:value>500000</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Specify order as mentioned below in each view resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

use as above , make it proper with correct space for keywords.

Comment: it looks like view resolver problem..which view relover u r using and can you post a bit of that code to easily identify the problem ?

Comment: can you post your practiceType.jsp as well ?

Comment: I add servlet-context.xml - mb you right - this is because of view resolver - I'll try  now

Comment: check whatever  the string view logical name you are returning from controller is same as the definition name inside tiles /WEB-INF/views/views.xml file.

Comment: I try another view rersolver:<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>    but it didnt help

Comment: but when I del that line with jsp - it start to work

Comment: can you try with this header in your jsp                    <jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

Comment: try saving your jsp file with .jspx extension and make necessary view reolver suffix update ..

Comment: saving your jsp file with .jspx extension and make necessary view reolver suffix update .. –  this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncomment view resolver for jsp. Also specify

```
     <beans:property name="order" value="1" /> for internal view resolver and

     <beans:property name="order" value="0"/> for Tiles view resolver.
```

This ensures internalviewresolver will be assigned lowest priority than tiles resolver and it will resolve the view with view name.

Comment: I added this property:   <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
 </beans:bean> 
 
 <!-- Tiles config -->
 <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" >
  <beans:property name="order" value="0" />
 </beans:bean>

Comment: i'll try more tomorrow

Comment: Your practiceType.jsp should be in WEB-INF/views folder not in flows folder. Usually we put webflow flow xml files will be put under the flows. Move your jsp to views as this is what you specified in internalviewresolver.